# Issue with instagram downloader script

Tags: python

I have this script that seems to be working correctly but nothing is being downloaded.

```
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()

post_link = input("Instagram link: ")

try:
    if '/p/' in post_link:
        shortcode = post_link.split("/")[-2]
        post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, shortcode)
        L.download_post(post, target='C:\Downloads')
    else:
        L.download_post(post_link, target='C:\Downloads')

    print("Post downloaded.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

The downloads are seen in the [Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjvek.png) and when I hover over it in the terminal I can view the image, but when I go to the directory even through CMD, there is nothing there.

I tried multiple different target directories, rewrote some of the code but this is pretty simple and should work (and does work) but here we are.

Comment: ...sounds like maybe you're just looking at two different directories?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `instaloader` parameter `target` is just relative to where the python script is.

So for example if you put target `picture` a folder **with that name** will be created in the same folder that the python script is. Doesn't matter if you put an absolute path like you did in your code.

What I did below is use `os.chdir()` to change to the directory/folder I want to download the post and the target is set to `igpost` so the post will be downloaded in `C:\Downloads\igpost\`

```py
import os
import pathlib

import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()

post_link = input("Instagram link: ")

try:
    if "/p/" in post_link:
        shortcode = post_link.split("/")[-2]
        post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, shortcode)
        os.chdir(pathlib.PurePath("C:/Downloads"))
        L.download_post(post, target="igpost")
    else:
        os.chdir(pathlib.PurePath("C:/Downloads"))
        L.download_post(post_link, target="igpost")

    print("Post downloaded.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e!s}")
```